# How do I run two website on same domain with different port on Centos Apache

Tags: apache, centos7, virtualhost

I have already a website that is running on port 443. I am using CentOS 7 environment with Apache.

So, the domain is: https://www.example.com

Now, I have one more website and want to run this website on same with different port like 444. So, the final url for this website should be:

http://www.example.com:444

To run first website on port 443, I have done below things:

**Step 1:**  created a conf file in "/etc/httpd/sites-available/website1.conf". This file contains below code:

```
<VirtualHost *:443> 
      ServerName server-ip 
      ServerAlias server-ip 
      DocumentRoot "/opt/lampp/htdocs/website1/" 
      DirectoryIndex index.html index.php 
     <Directory "/opt/lampp/htdocs/live/"> 
       Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI 
       DirectoryIndex index.php index.html 
       AllowOverride All
       Order allow,deny 
       Allow from all 
     </Directory> 
</VirtualHost>
```

**Step 2:**  Enable this virtual host file so that Apache will know about this virtual host.

**Step 3:**  Go to host file "/etc/host" and make a entry of this virtual host against mentioned server-ip:
    my-server-ip   www.example.com

So, all of the above things are working and my website is running on domain www.example.com.

Now, I have created the another virtual host having same domain name but with different port number as follow:

**Step 1:** Created .conf file under "/etc/httpd/sites-available/website2.conf". This file contain below code:

```
<VirtualHost *:444> 
      ServerName same-server-ip 
      ServerAlias same-server-ip 
      DocumentRoot "/opt/lampp/htdocs/website2/" 
      DirectoryIndex index.html index.php 
     <Directory "/opt/lampp/htdocs/live/"> 
       Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI 
       DirectoryIndex index.php index.html 
       AllowOverride All
       Order allow,deny 
       Allow from all 
     </Directory> 
</VirtualHost>
```

**Step 2:** Enabled this new website.

**Step 3:** Added this port number in .conf file in /etc/http/conf/httpd.conf, just below of this line:

```
Listen 80  
Listen 444
```

**Step 4:** After that, restarted Apache.

Now, when I hit the URL: www.example.com:444, server is redirecting me to first one website www.example.com.

I am not able to figure out what thing I have missed. Can anyone please help me on this?

Comment: The application/site running on 444 is probably redirecting you

Comment: Thanks for reply. I don't know about how or why it is redirecting me

Comment: As a test, remove everything from `/opt/lampp/htdocs/website2/` and put only one simple index.html there, and see if it still redirects.

Comment: Make sure you test `https://www.example.com:444` and not `http://www.example.com:444` (HTTPS not http).  When something does not match, Apache uses the first `VirtualHost` listed in the configuration, from the top.

Answer (score 0):

Encountered a similar issue so i decided to reply even though it has been a while since this was posted.

Since this is redirecting its a sign that everything was working properly but you had a redirect command in your html.

You have to check your html meta tags for the redirect command it looks something like this